# Blur image on ios5

Tags: ios

I reference the website to blur image on iOS 5:

[link](http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2013/01/blur-effect-in-ios-applications/?lang=en)

the website offered plenty method to blur an image

at last i use

```
- (UIImage *)blurryImage:(UIImage *)image withBlurLevel:(CGFloat)blur;
```

to blur image.

It works fine on iOS 6, but encounter a problem on iOS 5

the problem happened in

```
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                outBuffer.data,
                                outBuffer.width,
                                outBuffer.height,
                                8,
                                outBuffer.rowBytes,
                                colorSpace,
                                kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
```

ctx is nil, and the error message is :

```
<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: invalid data bytes/row: should be at least 2560 for 8 integer bits/component, 3 components, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast.
```

What is that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the great Nick Lockwood's FXBlurView - which gives iOS 7 like blur to iOS 5 and higher

[FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView)

Comment: Why CGImageGetBitsPerComponent in CGBitmapContextCreate is 8?,

Answer (score 0):

You could either use `UIVisualEffectView`, or if you want more control, you could make use of Apple's `UIImageEffects` sample code.

Here's the sample code on iOS Developer Library : [Blurring and Tinting an Image](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UIImageEffects/Listings/UIImageEffects_UIImageEffects_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013396-UIImageEffects_UIImageEffects_h-DontLinkElementID_8)

And here's how to use it :

```
#import "UIImageEffects.h"
...

self.originalImageView.image = [UIImageEffects imageByApplyingLightEffectToImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];
```